# ¿Como mostrar, en un datagridview, la fecha, hora y el usuario que realizó una captura de datos?

Tags: c#

Me encuentro desarrollando un sistema en C# donde el usuario (ya registrado) se loguea para despues entrar a un menú principal. Dentro de éste accesa a esta ventana llamada "New Capture" donde es capaz de realizar capturas de datos que son mostrados posteriormente en un datagridview, pero no se como hacerle para que se muestre el nombre del usuario que realizó la captura así como también la hora y fecha en que fue elaborado. ¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor? Les anexo mi windowsform y mi tabla donde los quiero almacenar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código de la ventana login:**

```
    namespace AutoCompletarTextBox{

    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
    public frmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblHora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    public static String Codigo = "";

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblHora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string CMD = string.Format("select * from Usuarios where Username='{0}' and Password= '{1}'", txtUser.Text.Trim(), txtPass.Text.Trim());
            DataSet ds = Utilidades.Ejecutar(CMD);
            Codigo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id_usuario"].ToString().Trim();
            string cuenta = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString().Trim();
            string contra = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString().Trim();

            if (cuenta == txtUser.Text.Trim() && contra == txtPass.Text.Trim())
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status_admin"]) == true)
                {
                    frmMainMenuADMIN Mmenu = new frmMainMenuADMIN();
                    this.Hide();
                    Mmenu.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    frmMainMenuUSER Mmenu2 = new frmMainMenuUSER();
                    this.Hide();
                    Mmenu2.Show();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username/Password are incorrect.");
        }
    }

    private void frmLogin_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        frmPassChange pc = new frmPassChange();
        pc.Show();
    }
}}
```

**Código de la ventana New Capture:**

```
     namespace AutoCompletarTextBox
     {
     public partial class frmNuevaCaptura : Form
      {
          SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource= CP-PC; Initial Catalog= SisIndustrial; Integrated Security=true");

    public frmNuevaCaptura()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void frmNuevaCaptura_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conexion c = new Conexion();
        c.autoCompletar(textBox1);

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
        string fecha1 = dt.ToString("d", ci);

        String format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt";

        // Converts the local DateTime to a string 
        // using the custom format string and display.
        String str = dt.ToString(format);

        lblShowTime.Text = str;
    }

    private void btnNuevoPN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Num_Parte (Part_Number) values ('" + txtArea.Text.TrimEnd() + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Visteon Part Number added successfully to the database.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtArea.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtTipo.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtCliente.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtFamilia.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtProd.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || textBox1.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtoperador.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtTC.Text.TrimEnd() == "" || txtEFF.Text.TrimEnd() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the fields to continue.","Atention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }

        if (txtArea.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtArea, "Add the area.");
        }

        if (txtTipo.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtTipo, "Add a product type.");
        }

        if (txtCliente.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtCliente, "Add a customer.");
        }

        if (txtFamilia.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtFamilia, "Add a family.");
        }

        if (txtProd.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtProd, "Add a Production Line.");
        }

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Add a VPN.");
        }

        if (txtoperador.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtoperador, "Add the quantity.");
        }

        if (txtTC.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtTC, "Add the CT.");
        }

        if (txtEFF.Text == "")
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtEFF, "Add the eff.");
        }


        else
        {
            conexion.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into CWS (Area, Product_Type, Customer, Family, Production_Line, Part_Number, Quantity_Operators, Cycle_Time, Rate, Cws) values ('" + txtArea.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtTipo.Text.TrimEnd() + "' , '" + txtCliente.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtFamilia.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtProd.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + textBox1.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtoperador.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtTC.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtResultado.Text.TrimEnd() + "', '" + txtResultadoCWS.Text.TrimEnd() + "', )";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexion.Close();
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("New capture was added!", "Atention", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
    }



    private void btnSaveArea_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Area (Nombre) values ('" + txtArea.Text.TrimEnd() + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Area added succesfully to the database.");
    }

    private void btnSaveType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Tipo_Producto (Tipo) values ('" + txtProd.Text.TrimEnd() + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Product type was added succesfully to the database.");
    }

    private void btnCalcular3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fijo = int.Parse(lblfijo.Text); //3600     
        int tc = int.Parse(txtTC.Text);
        int rph = fijo / tc; //3600/tc= rate/hra (rph)
        txtResultado.Text = rph.ToString(); //el resultado que es un Rate/hora se almacenara en txtResultado [1]

        decimal eff = decimal.Parse(txtEFF.Text);
        int fijo2 = int.Parse(lblfijo2.Text); // /100
        decimal resp = eff / fijo2;
        lblresul.Text = resp.ToString();

        int resul1 = rph;
        decimal num2 = decimal.Parse(lblresul.Text);
        decimal reff = resul1 * num2;
        txtResultado2.Text = reff.ToString(); //el resultado, qe es un Rate con EFF, se almacenara en txtResultado2 [3]

        decimal operador = decimal.Parse(txtoperador.Text);
        decimal resul2 = reff;
        decimal div2 = operador / resul2; // cantidad de op / rate con eff =  new CWS con EFF
        txtResultadoCWSEFF.Text = div2.ToString(); // el resultado, que es NEW CWS CON EFF, se almacenara en [4]

        decimal operador2 = decimal.Parse(txtoperador.Text);
        decimal rph2 = rph;
        decimal div3 = operador2 / rph2; // cantidad de op / Resultado1 = CWS normal
        txtResultadoCWS.Text = div3.ToString(); // el resultado, que es el CWS, se almacena en [1]
    }

    private void btnSaveCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Cliente values ('" + txtCliente.Text.TrimEnd() + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Customer added succesfully to the database.");
    }

    private void btnSaveFam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Familia (Descripcion_Linea) values ('" + txtFamilia.Text.TrimEnd() + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Family added succesfully to the database.");
    }

    private void btnSaveProdLine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = conexion.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Producto (Descripcion_Subproducto) values ('" + txtProd.Text.TrimEnd() + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Production line was added succesfully to the database.");
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtArea.Clear();
        txtTipo.Clear();
        txtCliente.Clear();
        txtFamilia.Clear();
        txtProd.Clear();
        textBox1.Clear();
        txtoperador.Clear();
        txtTC.Clear();
        txtResultado.Clear();
        txtResultado2.Clear();
        txtResultadoCWS.Clear();
        txtResultadoCWSEFF.Clear();
    }

    private void txtoperador_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void txtTC_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;

        if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }



    private void txtResultadoCWS_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string v1 = txtEFF.Text;
        decimal v2 = Convert.ToDecimal(v1);
    }

    private void btnVer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmCWSTable cws = new frmCWSTable();
        cws.Show();
    }
```

**Código de la ventana Menu Principal:**

```
       public partial class frmMainMenuADMIN : Form
    {
    public frmMainMenuADMIN()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void perfilToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VentanaAdmin VenAdm = new VentanaAdmin();
        VenAdm.Show();
    }

    private void nuevaCapturaBWSToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmNuevaCaptura NuevaCap = new frmNuevaCaptura();
        NuevaCap.Show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Con lo que has puesto en tu pregunta es bastante difícil de ayudarte ¿Los usuarios de tu aplicación se logean o algo parecido? Mira la ayuda para completar una [buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Asi es, la persona se loguea, despues entra a un menu principal donde puede accesar a esta ventana por medio de un tool strip menu item.

Comment: Entonces debes poner toda esa información que es relevante para poder ayudarte y su código asociado.

Comment: Ya puse el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es que el constructor de tus clases `frmMainMenuADMIN` y `frmMainMenuUSER` reciban por parámetro el Usuario que acabas de validar. Lo mejor sería primero que tuvieras una clase para `Usuario` y así encapsular los campos que lees:

```
public class Usuario {
  string codigo {get; set;}
  string cuenta {get; set;}
  string contra {get; set;}
  boolean administrdor {get; set;}

  public Usuario (string código, string cuenta, string contra, boolean admin){
     //Las asignaciones normales
  }
}
```

Luego instancias el usuario y su pantalla para hacer las capturas pasándolo como parámetro:

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario(
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id_usuario"].ToString().Trim(),
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString().Trim(),
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString().Trim(),
   Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status_admin"]);

Form ventana; 
if (usuario.administrador)
     ventana = new frmMainMenuADMIN(usuario);
else
     ventana = new frmMainMenuUSER(usuario);

this.Hide();
ventana.Show();
```

En el método constructor de cada ventana recoges ese usuario para ponerlo donde necesites, suponiendo que fuera el operador sería:

```
txtoperador.Text = usuario.cuenta;
```

Y finalmente supongo que tendrás que modificar tu tabla en la base de datos para añadir un campo de `codigo` y ponerlo como `Foreign Key`.

Comment: Oh ya veo, mas tarde pruebo eso y te digo si me funcionó. Y con respecto a lo ultimo no será necesario, solamente me interesa que se muestre el nombre del usuario o bien el Username cualquiera de los dos.

Comment: Disculpa, lo de:

                 Usuario usuario = new Usuario(
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id_usuario"].ToString().Trim(),
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Username"].ToString().Trim(),
   ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Password"].ToString().Trim(),
   Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status_admin"]);

Form ventana; 
if (usuario.administrador)
     ventana = new frmMainMenuADMIN(usuario);
else
     ventana = new frmMainMenuUSER(usuario);

            this.Hide();
            ventana.Show();


En cual(es) ventanas lo coloco?

Comment: En el método dentro del `try` en `btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` de ventana login después de `DataSet ds = Utilidades.Ejecutar(CMD);`. Es una forma alternativa a como lo has puesto tú haciendo lo que te recomiendo yo. Sustituye al resto del `try`.

Comment: Ok, y con respecto a: "Usuario usuario = new Usuario", la palabra Usuario por que cosa lo debo de sustituir? porque me sale error cuando coloco asi literal.

Comment: Tambien te falto cerrar el primer parentesis, en donde va?

Comment: Yo veo los parentesis cerrados. Lo del error debe ser que no has hecho la clase Usuario. Haz la clase Usuario, rellena el código del constructor que puse e importa la clase en donde lo estes llamando (login y la form donde lo vayas a usar)

Comment: Ya logré pasar el username al textbox. Muchas gracias!